# Cambiar contraseña en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo intalado Auth de laravel, pero debo cambiar el password del usuario ya autenticado...

Creo la ruta que apunta al formulario para cambiar contraseña

Creo un formulario con un solo campo donde debe ingresar la nueva contraseña

Creo un controlador con las funciones 
   @formulario que returna el view del formulario
    @actualizapass que no se qué colocar ahi.

Cómo hago para actualuzar la contraseña?

Comment: Agrega el código. No sabemos como "creas" eso que dices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que ya tenías parte del trabajo hecho, pero ya que me mandaron a editar la respuesta, y para futuros hispanos que tengan tu misma duda y no puedan entender dada la forma en la que planteaste la pregunta, explicaré mas detalladamente.
Lo primero sería escribir las rutas

```
// En el archivo routes/web.php
Route::get('user/update/password', 'UserPasswordController@showForm');
Route::post('user/update/password', 'UserPasswordController@update');

// En el controlador (UserPasswordController.php)

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Auth;

class UserPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function showForm(Request $request)
    {
        // Infla la vista formulario de password
        return view('users.passwordform');
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Validar los datos
        $this->validate($request, [
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:32',
        ]);
        // Note la regla de validación "confirmed", que solicitará que usted agregue un campo extra llamado password_confirm

        $user = Auth::user(); // Obtenga la instancia del usuario en sesión

        $password = bcrypt($request->password); // Encripte el password


        $user->password = $password; // Rellene el usuario con el nuevo password ya encriptado
        $user->save(); // Guarde el usuario

        // Por ultimo, redirigir al usuario, por ejemplo al formulario anterior, con un mensaje de que el password fue actualizado
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Password actualizado');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @tesoner, considera editar tu respuesta y agregar una explicación sobre lo que hace tu código. Te invito a consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Así estará bien?

Comment: Hola @tesoner, quedó mejor.